# How to completely change the css position of an element on the page to appear in another part of the document flow?

Tags: forms, nested, css-position

I have a long form with text inputs, and in the middle of it, I'd like to insert a jquery upload (blueimp) file plugin which uses a form element.  I know that nested forms are not valid markup.  How can I use CSS to visually position a form element inside another form element without doing some messy absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like using an iframe to generate the content, and then inserting the iframe into the middle of the original form works quite well.  I'm unfamiliar with the caveats of iframes but everything seems to work fine.